# VML to (base64) image

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, base64, vml

I'm rendering graphs client side with SVG and canvas except for IE8 that uses VML. In order to make the graphs downloadable as images I base64 encode them as PNG-files.

So what are my options for VML?

Is there some client side VML to base64 image script?